# What do you call a fact that doesn't match the settings?

Tags: terminology

I am not sure what you call them exactly. I don't think it's a plot hole, because it's not related to the story itself.

Let me give you an example:

Let's say your novel is set in Italy, but everyone speaks German or English.

Is there a specific term to this?

Comment: What to call the *fact* idk, but the setting is an *alternate reality*. If everyone in Italy speaks German, the Allies must have lost.

Comment: Maybe, an *anomaly*

Comment: Asking for a general kind of word is **off-topic** but might be suitable on [elu.se], whereas if you mean a specific kind of word relevant to *writing*, then your question should be closed as **unclear**.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your example is an [anatopism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatopism), just as everyone speaking Latin would be an anachronism. But more generally, I think you're interested in incongruities.

Comment: Cool, I was really wondering if it was just a plothole. Guess asking the question was a good idea.

Comment: It's weird that it's not in the figure of speech or even in the narrative technique subsection.

Comment: @repomonster English has a word for nearly everything, but you can never be sure what Wikipedia will tell you about it.

Answer (score 10):

I'd go with **inconsistency**; to be even more specific, I'd say the worldbuilding is not consistent or poor.

I second J.G. in saying that you're interested in inconguities at large.